# Powershell Passing Information Through a Pipeline

Tags: powershell

Here is the situation, the auditors are in and asking for a report for all the users in certain groups with some account information plus which group they are in.  So what I did was to put all the requested groups in a txt file and use Get-Content and pipe it to a ForEach to do a Get-ADGropuMember to find all the users then a Get-ADUser in order to get all the properties they asked for.  The problem I'm having is that by the time I get that far into piping I no longer have the original group that triggered why the user account was selected.  Basically the script I have come up with so far:

`Get-Content '.\Scripts - Input\ADGroupIn.Accounts.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
  Get-ADGroupMember $_ -Recursive  -Server Accounts |
  Get-ADUser  -Properties SAMAccountName, Enabled, Name, Description, LastLogonDate, whenCreated | 
  Select-Object SAMAccountName, Enabled, Name, Description, LastLogonDate, whenCreated | 
  sort-object SAMAccountName} |
  Export-csv ".\Scripts - Output\SelectedGroups_Accounts.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

"Domain Admins" is a group name being read into the Get-Content.  The Get-ADGroupMember pulls in UserA, UserB, and UserC.  Then the Get-ADuser gets all the properties for each user but at this time I want to be able to append "Domain Admins" to the information for each user.  If I use the MemberOf property I will get all the groups the users are a member of when I need to show it was "Domain Admins" that put them on the list.

I haven't been working with Powershell for very long and would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-Content '.\Scripts - Input\ADGroupIn.Accounts.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
    $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember $group -Recursive -Server Accounts |
    Get-ADUser  -Properties SAMAccountName, Enabled, Name, Description, LastLogonDate, whenCreated | 
    Select-Object SAMAccountName, Enabled, Name, Description, LastLogonDate, whenCreated, @{n='Group';e={$group}} | 
    sort-object SAMAccountName
} | Export-csv ".\Scripts - Output\SelectedGroups_Accounts.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: From what I can see this addressed the problem.  Thanks